(Error) OSError: (WinError 6) The handle is invalid, when running python manage.py shell, I do not understand what is happening?
models.py file
# Create your models here.
class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    duration = models.IntegerField(null=False)

Then I run python manage.py shell in terminal
python manage.py shell
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.12.3 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.  

In [1]: from flights.models import Flight
Cancelling an overlapped future failed
future: <_OverlappedFuture pending overlapped=<pending, 0x1af989b8430> cb=[BaseProactorEventLoop._loop_self_reading()]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jaina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 66, in _cancel_overlapped
    self._ov.cancel()
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Above error happens, How can I resolve this, please help.

The reason for the error is that Django 5.0 is incompatible with Python 3.8, To remove this error just upgrade to a compatible version of the language, Django 5.0 supports Python 3.10, 3.11, and 3.12
Furthermore, The Django 4.2. x series is the last to support Python 3.8 and 3.9, if you really need to develop your project on Python 3.8 or 3.
